# How can I prove that the following T-SQL is bad for performance?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have recently inherited a codebase with a large amount of stored procedures. The system they are supporting is encountering numerous performance problems which I am looking in to.

A number of the stored procedures have a pattern like this:

1. Create Temp table
2. Build up dynamic SQL query to insert a bunch of records, e.g.

   ```
   DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
   SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO @tempTable
   SELECT SomeColumn, SomeColumn2, SomeColumn3, etc FROM MyTable'

   IF @someParam = [SomeValue]
       SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE SomeColumn = [SomeValue]';

   IF @someOtherParam = [SomeOtherValue]
       SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE SomeOtherColum = [SomeOtherValue]';
   ```
3. Execute this dynamic sql

   ```
   EXEC(@sql);
   ```
4. Select from the temp table and bring in a bunch of additional information to return to the client.

   ```
   SELECT
      ...
   FROM
      @tempTable
   INNER JOIN ...
   ```

My immediate thoughts are:

- *There is dynamic SQL, so no cache plans, meaning plans generated every time.*
- *There is an `INSERT` `SELECT` pattern, so table locking is more likely to be an issue.*

I have re-written some of the stored procedures in this way instead:

```
SELECT 
       ...
FROM
      MyTable 
INNER JOIN ...

WHERE
    (@someParam != SomeValue
     OR
     SomeColumn = SomeValue)
    AND
    (@someOtherParam != SomeOtherValue
     OR
     SomeOtherColumn = SomeOtherValue)
```

From comparing execution plans and client statistics in SQL Server Management Studio, I have not sped the stored procedures up so I am apprehensive about suggesting wholesale re-writes of all stored procedures.

I am trying to set up some profiling of a live customer scenario, but as yet have been unable to prove my thoughts.

**Can anyone offer any confirmation of the theory behind my thoughts, or any better ways of proving my suspicions?**

The problem is I have read that dynamic SQL is not always a closed case - i.e. it depends on how it is used. My understanding of locking also falls down at the fact that nowhere can I get 100% confirmation of how this type of `INSERT` `SELECT` will lock tables.